# embedding swf in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, fusioncharts

I need to embed swf generated from [fusionchart](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) to my drupal 7 node. Since there is no D7 version of swftools, I guess I have to use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) javascrpit library.

My question is, how can I use it with fusionchart to display graphs...??

Comment: Would this be a field or IN the body content?

Comment: One off or something you want to repeat? Do you need a WYSIWYG button?

Comment: What I want exactly is, fusionchart code will produce a swf file containing the graph. how can I display this graph on my drupal 7 node..?? I know I can use <object></onject> tag but I want to know how to get that graph generated by the php code into this tag..?? I want to know how to achieve it especially regarding to fusionchart.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Drupal Module that allows you to integrate FusionCharts.
http://drupal.org/project/fusioncharts

Otherwise, swfobject is already included in the latest version of FusionCharts JavaScript Library. Including FusionCharts.js provides you with all the necessary items required to render FusionCharts.

Comment: but, there is no drupal 7 version